# display whole stream while highlighting with grep

Tags: linux, grep, tail

I often use `tail -f | grep someregex` on log files. I have grep liased to `grep ---color=auto` so my matches are highlighted. If I want to see my matches in the context of the whole stream, how would I go about that? Essentially, I want to use tail + grep as a highlighter.

Comment: Could you please clarify? What do you mean by the whole stream? If you want the whole stream, just don't use `tail`, run `grep somepattern` directly. Could you give an example of the kind of process you are monitoring?

Comment: if I am tailing a log file, grepping on error messages, but want to see it in context of some debug messages leading up to that match, in real time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see your matches in context, use the `-C` option. To see all the lines, use a huge argument to `-C`, e.g.,

```
tail -f yourlogfile | grep -C9999 someregex
```

Comment: Not sure why I didn't try this, I just assumed the context arguments wouldn't work on streams. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, it is what you are looking for:

```
grep "someregex" yourFile
```

It will print the lines where the "regex" matches.

Comment: I'm using this on a log file, I would like to see it output in real time w/o interaction, hence the tail -f, but want to highlight matches

Comment: The matches are highlighted with your command. So what is your desired output?

Comment: Well, I think I understand you now, since I've seen @garyjohn answer. Is it your desired behavior?